# Android : TextView how to I put the text aligned with the right hand side of the TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview

This should be easy but is just doesn't work...

I want to simply display the text of my textview on the right hand side instead of the left

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/PasswordConfText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:text="Password Conformation:">
</TextView>
```

yet that doesn't change a thing. if I put right or left or center_horizontal...

what am I missing?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put `android:gravity="right"` instead `android:layout_gravity`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`?